# How can i store data from mysql to XML in Laravel 5?

Tags: mysql, xml, laravel

I need data fetching from MySQL to XML and echo it in Laravel 5.

This is how i traditionally did:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $node = $dom->createElement("data");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute("username",$row['username']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("login_attemp", $row['login_attemp']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("mobile", $row['mobile']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("email", $row['email']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
    }

    echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Now, i want the same to be done in Laravel 5, Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Laravel is written in PHP. Where are you getting stuck? What did you try?

Comment: @Evert I am also having same problem,can u pls help me

Comment: @XavierIssac this question has been answered. If you have the same problem, read the answer?

Comment: @Evert am getting error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\XMLWriter' not found

Comment: @XavierIssac you should learn how to use PHP namespaces. If you're having trouble, open a new question on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your question it's not quite clear what seems to be the problem.

You use the model to grab the data and then you turn it into xml like you've done before by using `DOMDocument` or probably better with `XMLWriter` i.e.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use App\User;

Route::get('/users/xml', function() {
    $users = User::all();

    $xml = new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openMemory();
    $xml->startDocument();
    $xml->startElement('users');
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $xml->startElement('data');
        $xml->writeAttribute('id', $user->id);
        $xml->writeAttribute('firstname', $user->firstname);
        $xml->writeAttribute('lastname', $user->lastname);
        $xml->writeAttribute('email', $user->email);
        $xml->endElement();
    }
    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->endDocument();

    $content = $xml->outputMemory();
    $xml = null;

    return response($content)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
});
```

Sample output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<users>
  <data id="1" firstname="John" lastname="Doe" email="john@example.com"/>
  <data id="2" firstname="Mark" lastname="Lee" email="mark@example.com"/>
  <data id="3" firstname="Jane" lastname="Doe" email="jane@example.com"/>
</users>
```

Comment: I am facing same problem, Can you plese look on to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925474/converting-sql-query-to-laravel-eloquent-query?noredirect=1#comment107794898_60925474

Comment: Am getting this error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\XMLWriter' not found