# Make an rss feed with Laravel 5.1

Tags: rss, laravel-5.1

I make application with Laravel 5.1 only I need to get some posts as XML in an RSS feed.

I am using Laravel 5.1. I found a lot of solutions for Laravel 4 which don't work for 5.1.

I tried this code, but how can I path my data to view?

```
return response('rss', 200,['Content-Type'=> "application/xml"]);
```

and this

```
return response($posts, 200,['Content-Type'=> "application/xml"]);
```

but this code returns only json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did it thanks every one this is my code

```
    $xml = new \XMLWriter();
    $xml->openMemory();
    $xml->startDocument();
    $xml->startElement('users');
    foreach($users as $user) {
        $xml->startElement('data');
        $xml->writeAttribute('id', $user->id);
        $xml->writeAttribute('firstname', $user->firstname);
        $xml->writeAttribute('lastname', $user->lastname);
        $xml->writeAttribute('email', $user->user->name);
        $xml->endElement();
    }
    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->endDocument();

    $content = $xml->outputMemory();
    $xml = null;

    return response($content)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

Answer Url

[How can i store data from mysql to XML in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014960/how-can-i-store-data-from-mysql-to-xml-in-laravel-5)